# Find the minimum number positive number in c++?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to find the minimum number using STL in C++, I know the syntax should be min(x,y). But I want to find the minimum +ve numbers in the list. Not including the negatives. How do I do that?

My numbers are in an array

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm...

Comment: What's the answer if all elements are negative?

Comment: in my problem there is no chance of that happening :) But i have got no cue in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finding the minimum number, it makes sense to use `std::min_element`. Fortunately, it comes with an optional comparison parameter, which we can make use of: ([sample here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/699916cec4329f2c))

```
auto pos = std::min_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr),
    [](const T &t1, const T &t2) {return t1 > 0 && (t2 <= 0 || t1 < t2);}
);
```

You just have to be careful to take into account that if it's comparing a positive `t1` to a negative number, it should always be true. If none of the elements are positive, this will give the location of the first number in the array. If 0 should be treated as part of the positives, change `t1 > 0` to `t1 >= 0` and `t2 <= 0` to `t2 < 0`.

Comment: Or just `[](T t1, T t2){ return as_unsigned(t1) < as_unsigned(t2); }` (See [GotW #93](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-93-solution-auto-variables-part-2/) for implementation

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with a suitable operation:

```
auto minpos = std::accumulate(myrange.begin(), myrange.end(), MAX_VALUE,
                              [](T acc, T x)
                              { return (x > 0 && x < acc) ? x : acc; });
```

Here `T` is the type of your elements and `MAX_VALUE` is the maximal value of that type (e.g. defined as  [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)).

Answer (score 0):

First use the remove_if algorithm to move all the negative numbers to the end of the collection, then call min_element on the positive range. In C++11

```
auto pos = remove_if(coll.begin(), coll.end(), [](int x){ return x < 0; });
auto min = *min_element(coll.begin(), pos);
```

If you're not using C++11 just replace the lambda with a pre-canned functor from  like less<>

Answer (score 0):

You may use `std::min_element` with `Boost::filter_iterator`

Something like:

```
struct is_positive_number {
  bool operator()(int x) const { return 0 < x; }
};

void foo(const std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
    typedef boost::filter_iterator<is_positive_number, base_iterator> FilterIter;

    is_positive_number predicate;
    FilterIter filter_iter_begin(predicate, begin(numbers), end(numbers + N));
    FilterIter filter_iter_end(predicate, end(numbers + N), end(numbers + N));

    FilterIter it = std::min_element(filter_iter_begin, filter_iter_end);

    if (it != filter_iter_end) {
        // *it is the min elem
    } else {
        // no positive numbers.
    }
}
```